# How to return last index with jnp.where in jit function

Tags: python, jit, jax

Say I have two arrays:

```
z = jnp.array([[5.55751118],
              [5.18212974],
              [4.35981727],
              [3.4559711 ],
              [3.35750248],
              [2.65199945],
              [2.02298999],
              [1.59444971],
              [0.80865185],
              [0.77579791]])

z1 = jnp.array([[ 1.58559484],
               [ 3.79094097],
               [-0.52712522],
               [-1.0178286 ],
               [-3.51076985],
               [ 1.30108161],
               [-1.29824303],
               [-0.19209007],
               [ 0.37451138],
               [-2.33619987]])
```

I would like to start at the first row in array z and find where in the second matrix a second value is within a threshold of this value.

example without @jit: I would like to return the last index of array z1. Value should be -3.51x

```
init = z[0]
distance = 2.6
new = init - distance 

def test():
    idx = z>=new
    val = z1[jnp.where(idx)[0][-1]]
    return val
test()
```

When using JIT (as needed in a larger scale model)

```
init = z[0]
distance = 2.6
new = init - distance 

@jit
def test():
    idx = z>=new
    val = z1[jnp.where(idx)[0][-1]]
    return val
test()
```

this error is produced:

```
ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: traced array with shape int32[].
The size argument of jnp.nonzero must be statically specified to use jnp.nonzero within JAX transformations.
The error occurred while tracing the function test at /var/folders/ss/pfgdfm2x7_s4cyw2v0b_t7q80000gn/T/ipykernel_85273/75296347.py:9 for jit. This value became a tracer due to JAX operations on these lines:

  operation a:bool[10,1] = ge b c
    from line /var/folders/ss/pfgdfm2x7_s4cyw2v0b_t7q80000gn/T/ipykernel_85273/75296347.py:11:10 (test)

See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `jnp.where` returns a dynamically-sized array, and JAX transformations like `jit` are not compatible with dynamically-sized arrays (See [JAX Sharp Bits: Dynamic Shapes](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#dynamic-shapes)). You can pass a `size` argument to `jnp.where` to make the result statically sized. Since we don't know how many elements will be returned, we can choose the maximum possible number of returned elements, which is `idx.shape[0]`. Since the result will be padded with zeros, the maximum index will give what you're looking for:

```py
@jit
def test():
    idx = z>=new
    val = z1[jnp.where(idx, size=idx.shape[0])[0].max()]
    return val
test()
```